# rewrite rule substitute argument

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is there any difference between

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)$ http://www.example.com/index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\/\-_]+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

In the first one base url is prefixed while in the second, it is not.
If there is any difference, then what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends upon whether the current site is on the domain www.example.com or not.

If the current site is www.example.com then your first rule is converted by Apache to become exactly the same as the second rule.

If the current site is anything other than www.example.com then rather than doing a silent rewrite, Apache will issue an external redirect (just as if you had added an `R` flag to the end of your RewriteRule).

For more details, see the [Apache mod_rewrite online documentation for RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and look at the section about the *Substitution* part of the rule.